# Convert time stored in DB based on DST

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, dst, java-time

I have times stored in DB.

```
ID  TYPE        STARTTIME    ENDTIME

1   WEEKDAY     08:00:00    18:00:00
2   SATURDAY    10:00:00    16:00:00
3   SUNDAY      10:00:00    16:00:00
4   HOLIDAY     10:00:00    16:00:00
```

Java code :

```
ZonedDateTime.of(date, entity.getStartTime(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

This is retrieving start time as 09:00:00 and end time as 19:00:00 when the day light saving ends.

Whats the best way to retrieve these times based on the day light saving?

Example

For a weekday I need to get the start time as 08:00:00 and end time as 18:00:00 irrespective of DST.

Comment: Which time zone do you want? Does the return value from `ZoneId.systemDefault()` agree with that? [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be weird to do, but you can convert it into `UTC` and then use [withZoneSameLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal-java.time.ZoneId-) for converting same instant into another zone

> This method changes the time-zone and retains the local date-time. The local date-time is only changed if it is invalid for the new zone, determined using the same approach as ofLocal(LocalDateTime, ZoneId, ZoneOffset).

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(),LocalTime.now() ,ZoneId.of("UTC"));

System.out.println(dateTime);  //2019-11-19T10:48:12.324356Z[UTC]

ZonedDateTime result = dateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));  // provide ZoneId.systemDefault()

System.out.println(result);    //2019-11-19T10:48:12.324356-06:00[America/Chicago]
```

Comment: Why do we need to get in UTC  and convert to local time zone? Why not ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(),LocalTime.now() ,ZoneId.systemDefault());

Comment: Your db might be in UTC timezone, which is recommended and when you convert that back using System default timezone. It will consider dst if your timezone has dst @Deepak

Comment: We are using the TIME datatype(MySql DB) for the lat 2 columns ( STARTTIME & ENDTIME) mentioned above. It stores the local time right?